# Ember.js - Multiple beforeModel Hooks

Tags: ember.js

Is there anything wrong with having multiple `beforeModel` hooks in an `ember` route?

For example, if I have a `mixin` that adds a `beforeModel` hook, and then another `beforeModel` in the route I'm "mixing in to".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you have it defined on the route and mixin, the route will win out.  In the example below, only `bar` will be called.

```
App.Foo = Ember.Mixin.create({
  beforeModel: function(transition, queryParams){
    console.log('foo');
  }
})

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.Foo,{
  beforeModel: function(transition, queryParams){
    console.log('bar');
  },
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/runufowe/1/edit

If you want though, you can call this._super(param1, param2...) from the extended class to call the base method.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.Foo,{
  beforeModel: function(transition, queryParams){
    this._super(transition, queryParams);
    console.log('bar');
  },
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/runufowe/4/edit

Answer (score 4):

kingpin2k is right that in his example the beforeModel hook of the IndexRoute wins. It's important to mention that you can invoke the inherited (but overriden) behaviours from App.Foo with `this._super();`.

```
App.Foo = Ember.Mixin.create({
  beforeModel: function(transition, queryParams){
    console.log('foo');
  }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.Foo,{
  beforeModel: function(transition, queryParams){
    this._super();
    console.log('bar');
  },
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/bibonila/2/edit